# Delete Oldest Files Until Free Space Threshold Is Met

Tags: terminal, command-line

I'd like to keep a minimum of 50GB free on a drive. What command can I run that will delete my oldest files and stop once the 50GB threshold is met? I'm guessing some combo of `du` and `rm` but have no idea how to string it all together.

Comment: The oldest file is most likely a file owned by the OS, *your* oldest file may be something obscure in ~/Library or similar. How do you want to restrict the deletions?

Comment: This is simply for backing up video files from one drive to another, so I'm not worried about deleting anything crucial. So, no need to restrict the deletions.

Comment: You still need to restrict it to said drive, I assume?

Comment: I probably would use find and sort to get a list of files sorted by size, use df to calculate how many bytes need to be freed, and then delete from the list till the threshold is reached.

Comment: Yes, I only want to delete old files on the destination backup drive. In essence, I want to free up 50GB so that when I do my next backup, I have 50GB of space for the newest files - not worried about losing older stuff in the event that my backup fails.

Comment: OK, sounds good... how do I do those things? Also: wouldn't I need find to sort by age, since I want to delete the *oldest* files, not the largest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132588/discussion-between-brijazz-and-nohillside).